# How can I read csv form kaggle

Tags: python, csv, kaggle

I want to read a csv-File from kaggle:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv')
print("Shape of dataframe is: {}".format(df.shape))
```

But I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv'
```

I took the file path from kaggle.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is that supposed to be downloaded from a web site?  `read_csv` can do URLs, but it has to be a URL.  Is it `'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/...'`?

Comment: Where is the `kaggle` directory ? if the file is within a sub-directory called `kaggle` you need to remove the leading `/`. Having the leading `/` makes OS think that you're trying to access a file by providing an [absolute path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm). So instead of `df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv')`, change it to `df = pd.read_csv('kaggle/input/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adapt that path to the downloaded file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv')
```

Is only an example path. Everyone has to change this path to the location where the downloaded .csv file from their homepage got saved.

The .csv file for download is available here:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset

Comment: Hello @teris, how do I adapt the path to the download file? Thank you.

Comment: if you save the in a C:\mydata\WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv  folder then the command would be: pd.read_csv('C:\mydata\WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv')

If this does not help google for "absolute file path" . thats the string that belongs into the parenthesis  ('absolute file path')